# Upgrade Magento 2 Commerce 2.3.2 to 2.3.4 not working

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2-enterprise

I'm trying to upgrade Magento 2 Commerce version from 2.3.2 to 2.3.4 using the following command.

> composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.3.4

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: magento/page-builder-commerce[1.2.0, 1.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: magento/page-builder-commerce[1.2.0, 1.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: magento/page-builder-commerce[1.0.1, 1.2.0].
    - magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.3.4 requires magento/page-builder-commerce 1.2.0 -> satisfiable by magento/page-builder-commerce[1.2.0].
    - Installation request for magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.3.4 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.3.4].
    - Installation request for magento/page-builder-commerce (locked at 1.0.1) -> satisfiable by magento/page-builder-commerce[1.0.1].
```

Comment: Hi Sudhanshu, Could you please try with require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.3.4 --no-update and then composer update, it is working fine at my system as I am also upgrade from 2.3.2 to 2.3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Hitesh.

> composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.3.4 --no-update

then

> composer update
>
> bin/magento setup:upgrade